# how to prevent message re-queue within rabbitmq server?

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, message-queue

I'm using direct exchange to publish messages to certain queues with routing keys, all configured in rabbit-server not code, I'm consuming messages with spring micro-service  then some failures happens within the receiving method, then the message re-queued causing loop, so I'd like to add a policy with rabbit-server to prevent that kind of re-queuing, could it be added as an argument while binding queue with exchange with specific routing key, or it should be a policy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On any exception by default spring send nack with requeue "true". If in your spring consumer application you want to send requeue false, then  throw the exception "AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException". So your consumer code should loook something like this :

```
`void onMessage(){
  try{
    // Your Code Here
  } catch(Exception e){
     throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException();
  }
}`
```

Comment: thanks for reply, it doesn't help too much in my case because the try block was using spring jpa to save the received message then SqlExceptionHelper (unique constraint violated ) happens somewhere else not caught in my block, so can I handle that in rabbit-server instead ?

Comment: if a message is consumed , then either it get processed successfully or it will failed to get processed. And then if it failed to get processed then it should be either handled manually or need to be rejected. In your case it is unable to get processed and the exception is passed to the SQLExceptionHelper. So why don't you throw it from the place where you are handling that exception.

Comment: Because now same consumer thread is throwing the exception, it a matter of get control of the exception in that thread and throw it in your way.

Comment: thanks Manmay, I tried it but there was some problem on EventListener method was annotated with Transactional which tries to commit the message to db which causes a loop, now it works fine without Transactional